# Quotes in makefile

Tags: makefile, gitlab-ci

this is my first post here (maybe more later ^^)

So, here we are :
I'm using Gitlab-CI, docker, makefile, firebase.

So in my Makefile :

```
firebase-deploy: ## Deploy the application
    $(FIREBASE) deploy -m "$(comment)"
```

in my CI :

```
variables:
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
  MESSAGE: $CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE

deploy-firebase:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - make install
    - make deploy comment="$MESSAGE"
```

The problem is actually, i have

```
docker-compose exec -T js node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/bin/firebase.js deploy -m "test ci ?
/bin/sh: syntax error: unterminated quoted string
```

So, as you can see, the double quote at the end is ... not here.
I tested a few things

```
\"Comment\"
\'Comment\'
"Comment\"
```

And more, but none of them work.
One thing interesting is that if i commit FROM gitlab.com it work as expected, but from my computer on push : nop.

Do you have any advice, or something to look for ?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you check the value of `$CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE`? Does it contains, for instance, quotes or end of lines?

Comment: `$ echo $MESSAGE\"`
`test CI"`

Seems that the message have nothing more, not space, not end of line etc...

Comment: Well, `echo` is not ideal for this kind of debugging. I would probably try to add two more scripts in your CI file: `printf 'X%sX\n' "$CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE"` and `printf 'X%sX\n' "$MESSAGE"`.

Comment: You are right then. On a commit from my computer, there is a new line before the second X, from the commit message, but on the commit directly from gitlab, all in a row.

Comment: Not surprised. You could, instead, pass the message in a text file. Or pre-process it (`base64` or other) to encode it before passing it to make and decode it in the make recipe.

Comment: Why are you not surprised ? 

Hmm, is there maybe a way to remove end of line ?

Comment: I am not surprised because I suspected this from the beginning. It was a very plausible explanation of your problem. See my answer for a possible fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your commit message contains end of lines you cannot pass it to your script as it is. Try, maybe, to substitute end of lines by another character, e.g. `-`. Of course the way to do it depends on the shell that executes your CI scripts. If it is bash, for instance, the following should work:

```
make deploy comment="${MESSAGE//$'\n'/-}"
```

If you must also escape other characters you can chain substitutions. Example if you want to substitute end of lines and double quotes by `-` and `'`:

```
c="${MESSAGE//$'\n'/-}"; c="${c//\"/\'}"; make deploy comment="$c"
```

To learn more about these bash substitutions just type `man bash` and read section *EXPANSION*, sub-section *Parameter Expansion*. The parameter expansion I used is:

```
${parameter/pattern/string}
```

that replaces `pattern` by `string` in the value of variable `parameter` (in bash parlance parameter is another name for variable). When the pattern begins with a `/` all matches of `pattern` are replaced with `string`, else only the first match is replaced. So the first parameter expansion:

```
c="${MESSAGE//$'\n'/-}"
```

substitutes all end-of-line characters in the value of variable `MESSAGE` by `-` (more on `$'\n'` later) and assigns the result to variable `c`. Note the enclosing double quotes, they are needed because you can have spaces in the message. And the second:

```
c="${c//\"/\'}"
```

substitutes all `"` in the value of variable `c` by `'` and assigns again the result to variable `c`.

In this case the most complicated is to put a end-of-line character in the first pattern, a double quote in the second and a single quotes in the second string. The `$'string'` construct is explained in the *QUOTING* section of the bash manual:

> Words of the form $'string' are treated specially. The word expands to
> string, with backslash-escaped characters replaced as specified by the
> ANSI C standard.

So `$'\n'` is replaced by the end-of-line character. In the second pattern and string you just need to escape the double and single quotes with a backslash to have them interpreted literally.

Finally the 3 commands of this little shell script are chained by `;`, the bash sequence operator. They are executed one after the other in the same bash invocation.

Comment: You will probably need to escape any literal double quotes as well, or instead.

Comment: Yes, that worked ! Thanks !
Since i am quite new to scripting, can you explain a bit how does this work ? (If not, it's ok, it should be ressource everywhere for it ^^)

Comment: I added some explanation but the best resource here is the bash manual.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation ! I'll read more about too